# copy and paste without certain values

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

simple question:
I have 2 columns, and I want to do a copy and paste without considering values equal to 0

```
A B
x 1
w 0
z 1
```

Then I need the result to be the following:

```
A B
x 1
z 1
```

Any comments / suggestions are welcome.
Thx a lot

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Use a filter. Filter out `0` and copy/paste visible cells. You can find many examples of this strategy by searching this site

Answer (score 0):

- Copy/paste everything
- then in your destination sheet replace "0" with "" using CTRL+H
- then press F5 > "Special..." > "blanks"
- then press    CTRL + "-"    and    select "entire row".

Comment: Hi, thanks for answering. The problem with this is that I have values in columns parallel to the paste cell. So it will also eliminate them. Any way to avoid this?

Comment: Paste it first in an empty sheet, delete unwanted rows using steps above and then copy/paste it again in your final destination sheet.

Comment: in sheets you could do this with an arrayformula like the below. Presumably you could make such an array formula in Excel's style, too. =arrayformula(split(transpose(split(textjoin("/",true,arrayformula(if(B1:B5=0,"",A1:A5&","&B1:B5))),"/")),","))

Answer (score 0):

Since you did not specify where you are pasting the data, I will paste on a new sheet (`Sheet2`) in the first available blank spot in `Col A`. I am assuming you have headers already on every sheet.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Filter()

Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")

Dim ws1LastRow As Long: ws1LastRow = ws1.Range("A" & ws1.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim ws2LastRow As Long: ws2LastRow = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

With ws1
  If Not .AutoFilterMode Then .Range("A1").AutoFilter 'Check for filter
    .Range("A1:B1").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<> 0" 'Apply filter (hide 0's)
    .Range("A2:B" & ws1LastRow).Copy 'Copy
    .AutoFilterMode = False 'Remove Filter
End With

ws2.Range("A" & ws2LastRow).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues 'Paste

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

You will need to swap every instance of `Sheet1` with the sheet name that has your raw data & you will need to swap every instance of `Sheet2` with the name of the sheet where you are pasting your data.